# Confused with input/type validation and monads

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, functional-programming

I just got to know better functional programming and how many stuff we have in javascript that I did not know it was actually functional.

So I think I understood the idea of the monad and functors. The thning I don't get is,e specificaly in javascript, how validating type/inputs with libs like monet or validate, makes any of the code cleaner than just return an Either with its value being the error value?

I like [this talk](https://youtu.be/Nrp_LZ-XGsY?t=2320) because it explains in way I can better understand the idea behind fp and composition at least, but the implementations that I have seem in javascript does not help with readabitlity.

Just to give an example let say I have the following code:

```
function Just(aValue) {
    this.v = function () {
        return aValue;  
    }
}

 function Invalid(anError) {
    Just.call(this, anError); //call the parent because this function does nothing but change the instance type.
    this.prototype = Object.create(Just.prototype); //we set the prototype to the function we want to inherit.
    this.constructor = Invalid; // we set back the constructor to the this function so it gets its instance type.
  }
  function Title (aTitle) {
    //cant be blank
    if (aTitle == '') {
        return new Invalid ('Title can\'t be blank');
    }
    //cant be bigger than
    if (aTitle.length > 45) {
        return new Invalid ('Title can\'t be bigger then 45 chars');
    }
    return new Just(aTitle);
}

function Description (aDescription) {
    if (aDescription) {
        //cant have more than 3 lines and 
        if (aDescription.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length > 3) {
            return new Invalid ('not more than 3 lines');
        }    
        //line cant be bigger than 65 chars
        for (var index = 0; index < aDescription.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length; index++) {
            if (aDescription[index].length > 65) {
                return new Invalid ('lines cant be bigger than 65 chars');
            }

        }
    }

function Item(aTitle, aDescription) {

    this.Title = new Title(aTitle),
    this.Description = new Description(aDescription)

}
var validItem = new Item('ValidTitle', 'ValidDesc');
//returns {Title:Just<ValidTitle>,Description:Just<ValidDesc>}
var InvalidItem = new Item('','');
//returns {Title:Invalid<'Title cant be empty'>,Just<''>}
```

This will return an Item object with errors or not, which I believe can be easily be retrieved by checking the types of the Item obj literal returned. Let's say this gets way bigger or whatever reasons gets more complicated than that. How can the "monad" validation help me? Any examples in javascript similar to the talk would be great.

The example code is just me trying to grasp the idea in practice. No idea id that is a proper implementation or not. FIY it is the way it is on purpose, I know es6 has proper classes and etc. This is all for the sake of understanding the concepts.

Thank you all.